# Draw after Form is loaded

Tags: c#, drawing, transfer

Since a week iam learning/working with System.Drawing. It works fine for me. Now i want to transfer data from **Form 1** to my **second Form** and want to have 2 Rectangles drawn on my **Form 2** after Form 2 loaded. How do i do that?

What i have tried so far:

- Invoke on Form 2_Load
- onPaint() <-- cant transfer Data
- event *show* (Form event)
  ...

(The Code below only works if i press a button on the second Form after Form 2 is loaded.)

#### Thats how my code looks like for this part:

**Form 1:**

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> _basen = new List<string>(); //Add some stuff
        _basen.Add("400;200;45");
        _basen.Add("400;200;45");
        Feld f = new Feld();
        this.Hide();  
        f.transferGameBase(_basen);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**Form 2:**

```
public void transferGameBase(List<string> infoBase)
    {
        int count = 0;

        foreach(string _base in infoBase)
        {
            string[] _splitter = infoBase[count].ToString().Split(';');
            drawBase(Convert.ToInt16(_splitter[0]), Convert.ToInt16(_splitter[1]), Convert.ToInt16(_splitter[2])); //[0] = x , [1] = y, [2] = size
            count++;
        }
        
    }

    private void drawBase(int x, int y, int size)
    {
            Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), x, y, size, size);
 
    }
```

Thanks for any answer =)!

Comment: You are drawing to a window that is not yet visible.  Never, *never* use CreateGraphics(), always use the Paint event.

Comment: This was on of my first ideas. But the problem is i dont know how to transfer the Paint event. If i say:                            private void drawBase(int x, int y, int size ,PaintEventArgs e)     i would have to transfer PaintEventArgs from somewhere. And i cant say null for e

Comment: The Paint event already gives your the `e` you need.  You need to store *infoBase* in a field of your class so it is available later when the Paint event fires.

Comment: Well, i did a new project. Works fine now. i only draw with the paint event now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public void transferGameBase(List<string> infoBase)
    {
        int count = 0;

        foreach(string _base in infoBase)
        {
            string[] _splitter = infoBase[count].ToString().Split(';');
            drawBase(Convert.ToInt16(_splitter[0]), Convert.ToInt16(_splitter[1]), Convert.ToInt16(_splitter[2])); //[0] = x , [1] = y, [2] = size
            count++;
        }

        this.Invalidate();

    }
```

Basically, windows only redraws the form when it actually needs to, so when you manually draw something on top of it, you need to tell the form to redraw itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could force the paint even to use your graphics with
the InvokePaint method

```
 private void drawBase(int x, int y, int size)
    {
            Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), x, y, size, size);
            this.InvokePaint(this, new PaintEventArgs(g, this.Bounds));

    }
```

But this still won't do anything since the graphics is created before the object is shown, and is prolly not what you want.

You should prolly add the rectangles to a variable on the form and handle drawing those in the Paint event.

Comment: This gives me a System.StackOverflowException error. Thanks for your try